# R - Count Number of Credit transactions per customer

Tags: r, dataframe, counting

I have a dataset that looks like this. I need to count the number of Credit transactions made by a customer from the given number.

```
>head(reqDs,15)
 Txn_date  Cust_no    Acct_no cust_type   Credit
1  2013-12-02 14607902  203612500         I   400.00
2  2013-12-02 14607902  203612500         I   300.00
3  2013-12-02 14607562 1603700605         I   304.71
4  2013-12-02 14607162 1405015800         O   475.00
5  2013-12-02 14607002  201694364         I   325.00
6  2013-12-02 14604662 1884614220         I  1390.00
7  2013-12-02 14604302  605847862         I   100.00
8  2013-12-02 14603582 1077033921         I   500.00
9  2013-12-02 14602322 1281344287         I     5.00
10 2013-12-02 14602322 1281344287         I   130.00
11 2013-12-02 14601322  204827461         O 15975.00
12 2013-12-02 14601322  204827461         O  3711.00
13 2013-12-02 14601322  204827461         O 12530.50
14 2013-12-02 14601080  465277103         O  3312.00
15 2013-12-02 14601080  465277103         O   370.00
```

I have tried using aggregate() and then applying the count() function from plyr package

```
noOfTxns <- aggregate(reqDs$Credit, by=list(reqDs$Cust_no), FUN=count)
```

But I am getting the following output instead of the desired output

```
    Group.1 x
1   14722   1000
2   15502   4686.99
3   15942   110
4   15948   c(30, 100)
5   16122   c(200, 200.54, 241.3)
6   16442   c(200, 400, 480, 600)
```

How do I get the required output which looks exactly like this?

```
    Cust_no  No_of_txns
1   14722    1
2   15502    1
3   15942    1
4   15948    2
5   16122    3
6   16442    4
```

Comment: I think you want `length` instead of `count`

Comment: There you go @RichardScriven !! I got it..

Comment: In `dplyr` this is the same as `count(df, Cust_no)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Courtesy : @RichardScriven

The answer is using length instead of count..

```
noOfTxns <- aggregate(reqDs$Credit, by=list(reqDs$Cust_no), FUN=length)
```